# Could you share a link to an URL parsing implementation?

Tags: java, string, parsing, url, scala

As far as I understand, an URL consists of the folowing fields:

- Protocol (http, https, ftp, etc.)
- User name
- User Password
- Host address (an IP address or a DNS FQDN)
- Port (which can be implied)
- Path to a document inside the server documents root
- Set of arguments and values
- Document part (#)

as

```
protocol://user:password@host:port/path/document?arg1=val1&arg2=val2#part
```

I need a code to get value (or null/empty value if not set) of any of these fields from any given URL string. Am I to implement this myself or there is already a code for this so I don't need to invent a wheel?

I am particularly interested in Scala or Java code. C#, PHP, Python or Perl code can also be useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The URL class gives you everything you need.
See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

```
URL url = new URL("protocol://user:password@host:port/path/document?arg1=val1&arg2=val2#part");
url.getProtocol();
url.getUserInfo();
url.getAuthority();
url.getHost();
url.getPort();
url.getPath(); // document part is contained within the path field
url.getQuery();
url.getRef(); // gets #part
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the java.net.URI class for this. URLs are for real resources and real protocols. URIs are for possibly non-existent protocols and resources.

Comment: Then why should I use URI for URL if I am going to operate addresses of real web pages?

Comment: Because you asked for a parsing implementation, which is what java.net.URI is. java.net.URL is a connection mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, just use the [`URL` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).  It provides methods such as `getProtocol`, `getHost`, etc. to obtain the different parts of the URL.