# In Java, there is some URL parser?

Tags: java, parsing, url, extract

I know there is a URL class in Java, but I need methods to get the file extension of the page (html, php, asp, etc), the country of the domain (ca, au, br, jp, fr, etc), the type of the page(.net, .org, .gov, etc) and others.
Some of these methods, I did using String handling, but I think that a class done only for this can be more confiable.

Comment: You can make your own algorithm to determine those url parts.

Comment: Writing your own class will give you everything that you want

Comment: There is a site called the public suffix list (http://publicsuffix.org/) which details TLDs. The list is long and makes parsing for the correct TLD complex. If you are not trying to validate the TLD it may be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure there is a specific class to do what you are asking. Take a look at the URL class first, and the post below.

[Could you share a link to an URL parsing implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990640/could-you-share-a-link-to-an-url-parsing-implementation/3990658#3990658)

I think you will need to combine the data returned from the URL class, and your own parsing algorithm to get the small bits of data that are not available. This should be pretty simple to do though, as it sounds like it is everything after the last index of dot for the host and the path (if they actually exist, which is not guaranteed).

Answer (score 5):

I created a simple Java class that makes URL parsing in Java much easier.

https://github.com/juliuss/urlplus

It can be used to build urls and modify them programmatically.  It also handles relative urls.

You can see from the unit test it's very comprehensive:

```
// build a URL
URL u = new URL("http://www.shopobot.com/?search=ipod");

// check the parts of the url were set correctly
assertEquals(u.getProtocol().name(), "http");

u.setFragment("login");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.shopobot.com/?search=ipod#login");

// add a parameter
u.addParameter("abc", "123");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.shopobot.com/?search=ipod&abc=123#login");

// add a duplicate parameter
u.addParameter("abc", "456");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.shopobot.com/?search=ipod&abc=123&abc=456#login");

// remove a parameter
u.removeParameter("search");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.shopobot.com/?abc=123&abc=456#login");

// reset fragment
u.setFragment("");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.shopobot.com/?abc=123&abc=456");

// test an encoded paramter
u.addParameter("encoding", "this code = awesome!");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.shopobot.com/?abc=123&abc=456&encoding=this+code+%3D+awesome%21");

// remove both duplicate parameters
u.removeParameter("abc");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.shopobot.com/?encoding=this+code+%3D+awesome%21");

// change host and port
u.setHost("localhost").setPort(8080);
assertEquals(u, "http://localhost:8080/?encoding=this+code+%3D+awesome%21");

// remove a parameter and add a page number (int parameter)
u.removeParameter("encoding").addParameter("page", 2);
assertEquals(u, "http://localhost:8080/?page=2");

// set the path
u.setPath("electronics/");
assertEquals(u, "http://localhost:8080/electronics/?page=2");
u.setPath("/electronics/");
assertEquals(u, "http://localhost:8080/electronics/?page=2");

// increment a parameter 3 times
u.incrementParameter("page").incrementParameter("page").incrementParameter("page");
assertEquals(u, "http://localhost:8080/electronics/?page=5");
// make sure the correct page number is returned
assertEquals(u.getParameter("page", 1), 5);

// set the page number to 2 and remove it -- setting it to 1
// since 1 is considered default, it is removed completely
u.setParameter("page", 2).decrementParameter("page");
assertEquals(u, "http://localhost:8080/electronics/");

// make sure that page will not be decremented since we're at 1
u.decrementParameter("page");
assertEquals(u, "http://localhost:8080/electronics/");

// test that defaults work
assertEquals(u.getParameter("page", 1), 1);
assertEquals(u.getParameter("page", 10), 10);

// test relative paths
u.setPath("/electronics/photography/");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("http://localhost:8080/")), "electronics/photography/");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("http://localhost:8080/electronics/")), "photography/");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("http://localhost:8080/electronics/photography/")), "");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("http://localhost:8080/electronics/mp3-players/")), "../photography/");
// make sure when paths match, but authority doesn't results in full url return
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("http://www.shopobot.com/electronics/photography/")), "http://localhost:8080/electronics/photography/");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("http://localhost:80/electronics/photography/")), "http://localhost:8080/electronics/photography/");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("https://localhost:8080/electronics/photography/")), "http://localhost:8080/electronics/photography/");

// try some more complicated relative paths
u.setHost("x.com").setPath("/a/b/c/d/e.html").setPort(80);
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("http://x.com/")),"a/b/c/d/e.html");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("http://x.com/a/b")),"c/d/e.html");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("http://x.com/a/b?q=1")),"/a/b/c/d/e.html");
u.addParameter("q", 1);
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("http://x.com/a/b/c/d/e.html")),"?q=1");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("http://x.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h")),"../../../../e.html?q=1");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("x.com/x/y/z/")),"../../../a/b/c/d/e.html?q=1");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("x.com/a/b/c/d/x/y/e.html")),"../../../e.html?q=1");
u.addParameter("f", "a b c");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("x.com/a/b/c/d/x/y/e.html")),"../../../e.html?q=1&f=a+b+c");
u.setFragment("hello").removeParameter("f");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("x.com/a/b/c/d/x/y/e.html")),"../../../e.html?q=1#hello");
assertEquals(u.toStringFull(),"/a/b/c/d/e.html?q=1#hello");

//test parameters with relative paths
u = new URL("facebook.com");
u.addParameter("test", "hi");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("facebook.com/?test=hi")),"");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("facebook.com/?test=hi&hello=hey")),"?test=hi");
u.addParameter("hello", "hey");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("facebook.com/?test=hi&hello=hey")),"");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("facebook.com/?test=hi&hello=hey#wow")),"?test=hi&hello=hey");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("facebook.com/")),"?test=hi&hello=hey");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("facebook.com/#yo")),"?test=hi&hello=hey");
u = new URL("facebook.com/#yo");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("facebook.com/")),"#yo");

//test relative paths with parameter changes
u = new URL("example.com/?param=1");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("example.com/?param=2")),"?param=1");
u = new URL("example.com/?param=1&param=2");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("example.com/?param=1&param=4")),"?param=1&param=2");
u.removeParameter("param");
assertEquals(u.toStringRelative(new URL("example.com/?param=1&param=4")),"/");

// build a new URL to test empty and null parameter values
u = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
u.addParameter("test", "");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/?test");
assertEquals(u.getParameter("test", "this is not returned"), "");
u.addParameter("this is a test", null);
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/?test&this+is+a+test");
u.addParameter("", "");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/?test&this+is+a+test");    
u.addParameter(null, "");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/?test&this+is+a+test");
u.addParameter("", null);
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/?test&this+is+a+test");
u.addParameter(null, null);
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/?test&this+is+a+test");
u.removeParameter("this is a test");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/?test");
u.removeParameter("");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/?test");
String[] nullGuy = null;
u.removeParameter(nullGuy);
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/?test");
u.removeParameter("test");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/");
u.addParameter(" "," ");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/?+=+");
u.addParameter("+","+");
assertEquals(u.getParameter("+", ""), "+");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/?+=+&%2B=%2B");
u.removeParameter(" ").removeParameter("+");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/");

//test fragment encoding
u.setFragment("short");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/#short");
assertEquals(u.getFragment(),"short");
u.setFragment("/this/is/a/#/<long>/( fragment )/");
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/#/this/is/a/%23/%3Clong%3E/(+fragment+)/");
u.setFragment(null);
assertEquals(u, "http://www.google.com/");

u = new URL("www.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA");
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("org"), true);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority(".org"), true);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("pedia.com"), false);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("wikipedia.org"), true);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("uwikipedia.org"), false);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority(".wikipedia.org"), true);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("en.wikipedia.org"), false);
u.setHost("sub.en.wiki.com");
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("com"), true);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("wiki.com"), true);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("en.wiki.com"), true);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("sub.en.wiki.com"), true);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("asub.en.wiki.com"), false);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("a.sub.en.wiki.com"), false);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("sub.en.wiki.com","asub.en.wiki.com"), true);
assertEquals(u.matchesAuthority("a.sub.en.wiki.com","asub.en.wiki.com"), false);

//test no protocol on factory style methods
u = URL.get("www.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA");
u = URL.get("www.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA", u);

u = new URL("shopobot.com");
u.setParameter("will this <#> be encoded?","we've gone batshit crazy! seriously!");
u.setFragment("what's our # again?");
assertEquals(u.toString(),"http://shopobot.com/?will+this+%3C%23%3E+be+encoded%3F=we%27ve+gone+batshit+crazy%21+seriously%21#what's+our+%23+again?");
assertEquals(u.getParameter("will this <#> be encoded?", ""), "we've gone batshit crazy! seriously!");
assertEquals(u.getFragment(), "what's our # again?");

u = new URL("www.en.shopobot.com");
assertEquals(u.getAuthoritySize(), 4);
assertEquals(u.getAuthority(-1),"");
assertEquals(u.getAuthority(0),"");
assertEquals(u.getAuthority(1),"com");
assertEquals(u.getAuthority(2),"shopobot.com");
assertEquals(u.getAuthority(3),"en.shopobot.com");
assertEquals(u.getAuthority(4),"www.en.shopobot.com");
assertEquals(u.getAuthority(5),"www.en.shopobot.com");

u = new URL("en.wikipedia.org:90210/a/b/c/d/e.html?test=true");
assertEquals(u.getChildDirectory("a"),"b");
assertEquals(u.getChildDirectory("b"),"c");
assertEquals(u.getChildDirectory("c"),"d");
assertEquals(u.getChildDirectory("d"),"e.html");
assertEquals(u.getChildDirectory("e.html"),"");
assertEquals(u.getChildDirectory("g"),"");

assertEquals(u.getParentDirectory("a"),"");
assertEquals(u.getParentDirectory("b"),"a");
assertEquals(u.getParentDirectory("c"),"b");
assertEquals(u.getParentDirectory("d"),"c");
assertEquals(u.getParentDirectory("e.html"),"d");
assertEquals(u.getParentDirectory("e"),"");

//test relative url creation
u = new URL("http://www.example.com");
URL u2 = u.resolveRelative("q.html");
assertEquals(u2.toString(), "http://www.example.com/q.html");
u2 = u.resolveRelative("/q.html");
assertEquals(u2.toString(), "http://www.example.com/q.html");
u = new URL("http://www.example.com/abc/");
u2 = u.resolveRelative("q.html");
assertEquals(u2.toString(), "http://www.example.com/abc/q.html");
```

Comment: Supurb. Solves url encoding at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such class. Some of these things (country code) are ill-posed and ambiguous, and often can't be determined from the URL alone. They're not parsing so much as lookup or inference. Other things (file extension) are not defined for most pages.