# Java - Extracting a string from another string

Tags: java, string

I have a String like this:

```
http://www.fam.com/FAM#Bruno12/06/2011
```

How can I cut `http://www.fam.com/FAM#` and `12/06/2011` in order to get only `Bruno`.

The format is always:

```
http://www.fam.com/FAM#NAMEDATE
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Can you just explain me how?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: subString method is your friend.

Comment: I wouldn't use substring. It's not very future-proof and doesn't well express in code that he's after the part section of a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string always starts with `http://www.fam.com/FAM#` then it's simple: that's 23 characters, so take the substring from position 23 (note that indices are zero-based).

```
String input = "http://www.fam.com/FAM#Bruno12/06/2011";
String result = input.substring(23);
```

If you want everything after the first `#` in the string, then search for `#` and take everything that comes after it:

```
int index = input.indexOf('#');
String result = input.substring(index + 1);
```

(error checking omitted for simplicity).

To remove the date, remove the last 10 characters.

See the API documentation of class `String` for useful methods.

Comment: He also wants to remove the date.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
myString = original.substring(23, original.length() - 10);
```

- `23` is for `http://www.fam.com/FAM#`
- `original.length() - 10` is for `12/06/2011`

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
String str = "http://www.fam.com/FAM#Bruno12/06/2011";
String[] arr = str.split("#|[\\d+/]"); // last index of arr is Bruno
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex `#(.*?)\\d\\d/` to capture it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use standard URL parsing code, as at [Could you share a link to an URL parsing implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990640/could-you-share-a-link-to-an-url-parsing-implementation/3990658#3990658)

I expect the URL parser can cope with the fact that your `Ref` (i.e. "Bruno12/06/2011") contains slashes.

```
URL url = new URL(inputString);
String nameDate = url.getRef();
```

expresses what you want to do in the simplest and clearest form.