# how to get image using html parsing with jsoup

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I want get all images using html parsing with jsoup.
I use below code ;

```
Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(jpe?g)]");
        for (Element image : images) {

            //System.out.println("\nsrc : " + image.attr("src"));
            arrImageItem.add(image.attr("src"));

        }
```

I parse this method all images but i want to parse this url

> http://tvrehberi.hurriyet.com.tr/images/742/403742.jpg

I want to parse beginnig of this url

> http://tvrehberi.hurriyet.com.tr/images .... .jpg

How to get parse like this ?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what your problem was. Is it maybe, that you only get relative URLs like `some/where/image.jpg` and want the absolute URL instead?

Comment: I know that is a old question but have you solved? Can you help me?

Comment: Yes. you can see answer in below. It is the correct answer

Comment: @SukruK please i very need an help to parsing a webpage with images but i can't do it alone.. Can you help me? contact me please at dellai.davide@gmail.com Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably give you what you ask for, though your question is a bit unclear, so I can't be sure.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    Document doc = null;
    String url = "http://tvrehberi.hurriyet.com.tr";
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Element e : doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(jpe?g)]")) {
        if(e.attr("src").startsWith("http://tvrehberi.hurriyet.com.tr/images")){
            System.out.println(e.attr("src"));
        }
    }
}
```

So, this might not be a very "clean" solution, but the if-statement will make sure it only prints out the image URL's from the /images/-directory on the server.

Comment: I want a parse kind of this url http://tvrehberi.hurriyet.com.tr/images/742/403742.jpg  and i want to write beginnig part of url http://tvrehberi.hurriyet.com.tr/images/ other part  /742/403742 always change. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to retrieve the URL path up to a certain point and cut off the rest. Do you even have to do that every time? 
If you are only using URLs from the one site in your example, you could store `"http://tvrehberi.hurriyet.com.tr/images"` as a constant since it never changes. If, on the other hand, you fetch URLs from many different sites, you can parse your URL as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990640/could-you-share-a-link-to-an-url-parsing-implementation/3990658#3990658).
Anyway, if you shared the purpose of parsing the URLs, we certainly could help you more.